# Instagram cannot get permission for likes

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

Request URL:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=my-id-goes-here&redirect_uri=http://my-site-was-here.net&response_type=code&scope=likes
```

The request page then only asks for basic information.

> my-app is requesting to do the following:
>
> Access your basic information Includes photos, friend lists & profile info

Then when I try to use it in my python code, the error says:

```
(400) OAuthAccessTokenException-The access_token provided is invalid.
```

Did Instagram remove `likes` via API? I had this working before.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram now requires that you request special permission from them in order to LIKE media using their API. So you will not be able to like a photo with the API until Instagram grants you these permissions.

Here is where you request access: https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

FYI, here are guidelines from Instagram about requesting these permissions: "The ability to POST and DELETE likes, follows and comments is restricted to applications that offer business services and not consumer facing apps."

Comment: When did this take effect?

Comment: @User some time in the past couple of months. It's relatively new.